Simple banking program assistance in C#
I am developing a simple banking program and am having difficulty with the Rollback method and setting _reversed to be true. I keep being told that I need to set _reversed to true if, and only if the rollback process is successful. I feel like I am doing that, however if anybody could review my code, that would be very helpful.
Account class:
internal class Account
{
    private decimal _balance;
    private string _name;

    // Constructor Method
    public Account(string name, decimal balance)
    {
        _name = name;
        _balance = balance;
    }

    // Property, which is read only
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    // Public Methods
    public bool Deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount > 0)
        {
            _balance += amount;
            return true; // Deposit succeeded
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Amount to deposit needs to be greater than $0.00.");
            return false; // Deposit failed as one cannot deposit a negative amount
        }

    }

    public bool Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount > 0 && _balance >= amount)
        {
            _balance -= amount;
            Console.WriteLine($"{amount} has been withdrawn from your account.");
            return true; // Withdrawal succeeded
        }
        else if (amount <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Amount to withdraw needs to be greater than $0.00.");
            return false; // Withdrawal failed as withdrawal amount is negative number
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have insuffucient funds to make this withdrawal.");
            return false; // Withdrawal failed as there is insufficient funds
        }
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {_name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Balance: {_balance}");
    }
}

Transaction class:
internal abstract class Transaction
{
    protected decimal _amount;
    protected bool _success;
    private bool _executed;
    private bool _reversed;
    private DateTime _dateStamp;

    public Transaction(decimal amount)
    {
        _amount = amount;
        _executed = false;
        _success = false;
        _reversed = false;
        _dateStamp = DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    public virtual void Execute()
    {
        if (_executed)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Transaction has already been executed.");

        _executed = true;
        _dateStamp = DateTime.Now; // Record the current time when Execute is called
                                   
    }

    public virtual void Rollback()
    {

        if (_executed)
        {
            if (!_reversed)
            {
                _reversed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract void Print(); // Placeholder for transaction print details

    public bool Executed => _executed;
    public abstract bool Success { get; }
    public bool Reversed => _reversed;
    public DateTime DateStamp => _dateStamp;
}

WithdrawTransaction class, inherited from Transaction class:
internal class WithdrawTransaction : Transaction
{
    private Account _account;

    public WithdrawTransaction(Account account, decimal amount) : base(amount)
    {
        _account = account;
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        base.Execute();
        _success = _account.Withdraw(_amount);
    }

    public override void Rollback()
    {
        if (_success)
        {
            bool depositResult = _account.Deposit(_amount);

            if (depositResult)
            {
                base.Rollback(); // Will only occur if the rollback is successfully completed
            }
            else 
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Rollback failed.");
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Print()
    {
        if (_success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Withdrawal Transaction: {_amount:C} from {_account.Name} on {DateStamp}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Executed: {Executed}\nSuccess: {Success}\nReversed {Reversed}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public override bool Success => _success;
}

TransferTransaction class inherited from Transaction class:
internal class TransferTransaction : Transaction
{
    private Account _fromAccount;
    private Account _toAccount;

    public TransferTransaction(Account fromAccount, Account toAccount, decimal amount) : base(amount)
    {
        _fromAccount = fromAccount;
        _toAccount = toAccount;
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        base.Execute();

        // Perform withdrawal from source account
        bool withdrawalSuccess = _fromAccount.Withdraw(_amount);
        if (withdrawalSuccess)
        {
            // Attempt to deposit into destination account
            bool depositSuccess = _toAccount.Deposit(_amount);
            _success = depositSuccess;

            if (!depositSuccess)
            {
                // If deposit fails, rollback the withdrawal
                _fromAccount.Deposit(_amount);
                Console.WriteLine("Deposit failed. Withdrawal has been rolled back.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _success = false;
        }
    }

    
    public override void Rollback()
    {
        if (_success && !Reversed)
        {
            bool withdrawResult = _toAccount.Withdraw(_amount);
            if (withdrawResult)
            {
                bool depositResult = _fromAccount.Deposit(_amount);
                if (depositResult)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Rollback successful.");
                    base.Rollback(); // Call base method only if both actions succeed
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Rollback failed to deposit back into the source account.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback failed to withdraw from the destination account.");
            }
        }
        else if (Reversed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transaction has already been reversed.");
        }
        else if (!_success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transaction was not successful, so no rollback is needed.");
        }
    }

    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Transfer of {_amount:C} from {_fromAccount.Name}'s account to {_toAccount.Name}'s account");
        Console.WriteLine($"Executed: {Executed}\nSuccess: {Success}\nReversed {Reversed}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public override bool Success => _success;
}

DepositTransaction class inherited from Transaction class:
internal class DepositTransaction : Transaction
{
    private Account _account;

    public DepositTransaction(Account account, decimal amount) : base(amount)
    {
        _account = account;
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        base.Execute();
        _success = _account.Deposit(_amount);
    }

    public override void Rollback()
    {
        if (_success)
        {
            bool withdrawResult = _account.Withdraw(_amount);

            if (withdrawResult)
            {
                base.Rollback(); // Will only occur if the rollback is successfully completed
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("rollback failed.");
            }
        }
    }
    public override void Print()
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"Deposit Transaction: {_amount:C} into {_account.Name} on {DateStamp}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Executed: {Executed}\nSuccess: {Success}\nReversed {Reversed}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    public override bool Success => _success; 
}

I added checks to ensure only the base-rollback() method is induced if the rollback is successful

The classes that inherit from your "Transaction" class are only setting the "_reversed" as true only when the result of Withdraw/Deposit in the overriden method is true.

@MatFied Thanks for pointing this out - Is there a way I can set _reversed to be true only when the rollback is successful? I'm struggling with this aspect

You mean if "_success" in the Rollback method is true or after all other operations in the overriden Rollback are completed?

@MatFied After all operations in the Rollback are complete. All operations need to be complete, and then _success will need to be set to true

If you need to call the base.Rollback after all the operations in the overriden Rollback method are completed then add it at the end of the method.
If you need to call it only when _success is set to true then add it in the brackets.

@MatFied, I think I made an error in my previous message. I want to make sure that all the operations in rollback are completed successfully before changing _reversed to be true. I wonder if this might involve changing the base transaction class. _reversed should only ever be made true if the rollback operations are all completed, and completed successfully

Banking programs like this are always best done by internally keeping an opening balance, a list of transactions, and then computing a final balance. Then reversals are done by adding a second reversing transaction. Modifying the balance as you go is always fraught with danger.

The problem with the "Deposit transaction", is that you deposit before you withdraw, even though you intend to withdraw, and only then does the transaction "fail" and you need to "rollback". You wouldn't need to if you tried to withraw first (the more defensive case). There's also the issue of concurency. Databases use locking and logs.

I would suggest a bit of a frame challenge. Instead of trying to keep a current account balance you could just keep a sequence of transactions, and compute the balance from these transactions.
For example:
public record Account(string Name) { }

public class Transaction(Account from, Account to, decimal amount)
{
    public Account From { get; set; } = from;
    public Account To { get; set; } = to;
    public decimal Amount { get; set; } = amount;
}

public class Ledger
{
    private Stack<Transaction> transactions = new();

    public bool TryAdd(Transaction transaction)
    {
        var currentBalance = GetBalance(transaction.From);
        if (currentBalance > transaction.Amount)
        {
            transactions.Push(transaction);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public decimal GetBalance(Account account)
    {
        decimal balance = 0;
        foreach (var transaction in transactions)
        {
            if (transaction.From == account)
            {
                balance -= transaction.Amount;
            }

            if (transaction.To == account)
            {
                balance += transaction.Amount;
            }
        }
        return balance;
    }

Transactions can only be added to the ledger if the account balance does not dip bellow zero. This simple system have an obvious problem, how is money added in the first place? One solution is to allow negative balances, possibly with a per account limit. You could also have a special "central bank account" with an effectively infinite balance.
Another problem is performance, this approach do not scale well. Any real system would keep a balance per account to avoid processing all transactions ever made whenever someone wants to know how much money they have. But it is useful to think of this as a cache, the "real" balance is still determined from the all the transactions that have been made.
"Rollback" in this context could mean many different things. Do we simply remove transactions from the top? Do we remove the transaction, and any subsequent transactions that became invalid? Do we just fail the rollback if any subsequent transactions would become invalid?
A very simple approach is to just try to add a new "inverse" transaction:
public bool Rollback(Transaction t) => TryAdd(new Transaction(t.To, t.From, t.Amount));

Whatever we do we need to ensure the overall state is "valid" at any point in the transaction history.
This example takes no consideration for multiple banks, security, concurrency, or any other real world considerations. The main idea is that the current state is completely determined by the sequence of transactions.
